# Asp.Net Button control renders <span> but with update panel after update the <span> disappear

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I am creating a customized composite control including a button control, while it renders a `<span>` wrapper outside the `<input>` tag of button. However, if I put this customized control into an update panel and click on this button, after post back the update panel will change the button's render to only have `<input>` tag and delete `<span>` tab outside the `<input>`, which could potentially change my css selector.

1. why asp.net would generate a  for button control?
2. why update panel would change the button control's render?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `RenderMode` of the update panel to `Inline`.

**EDIT**

As a possible workaround, try wrapping the button in a `Label` control instead, since it resolves to a span when it's rendered anyway.

Comment: It would be the same, the RenderMode for update panel is to modify the Update Panel itself, either wrapped with <span> or <div>, it does nothing with <contentTemplate>. Just tried, nop!

Comment: The span does render after the postback without the update panel?

Comment: Yes, if without update panel, it would be a real postback, and regenerate all the controls again, so it would have <span> outside <input> for button control. but not with Update Panel, wired for me...

Comment: Instead of just wrapping it in a span, have you tried wrapping the button in a `Label` (resolves to a span)? I don't know why you should have to do that, but it might resolve your issue.

Comment: I don't want to wrap with any extra html tag, it's the UI.WebControls itself renders Button control with a <span> tag..........I don't want it at all.  :(

Comment: Oh, so you don't want the `span` tag rendered with the button? I thought you wanted it to leave the span alone... I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: yes, I don't want the <span>, but it's automatically generated by asp.net UI.WebControls. But if it generates that's fine, I am wondering why the updatepanel would remove it after postback?!

Comment: I was just looking at my markup, and I don't see the buttons wrapped with spans. You're custom control is inheriting from `Button` right?

Comment: it's bit complicated. its a class inherited from Calendar object and then added with Panel->Table(htmltable) ->Tablerow->tableCell->button.